# What is considered a segment in google analytics API?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am querying the google analytics API and get an error response saying:

> Selected dimensions and metrics cannot be queried together.

Using the dimensions-metrics-explorer I can find which dimensions and metrics can be queried together. https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/dimensions-metrics-explorer/

The dimension and metric I want to combine should be possible according to the explorer (CM Impressions and CM Campaign (CM Model))

However, if I tick the box `Only show fields that are allowed in segments` both those options disappear. So I assume that I am using segments in my request but I do not understand if I truly do or what a segment is.

These are the parts of my query:

```
auth: <auth>,
'max-results': 10000,
quotaUser: <quotaUserId>,
metrics: [ 'ga:dcmImpressions' ],
dimensions: [ 'ga:dcmLastEventCampaign', 'ga:date' ],
'start-date': <rangeStart>,
'end-date': <rangeEnd>,
id: [ <analyticsViewIds> ],
```

Am I using segments and if so, what is the segment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I using segments?

**No, you're making a regular query**

> what is the segment?

**[Segments](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123951?hl=en) are a special data querying feature**:

- **More advanced querying**: regular queries work on a per-session/hit level just inspecting actual rows of data and returning what matches. With segments you can go further:

  - **[User Scope](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en)** include data for users who meet certain conditions ([regular queries are all session/hit based](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en)), thus allowing you to filter data on criteria which span across sessions
  - **Session Sequencing** include/exclude data based on a series of action users took during their session (first this, then that, then immediately that...)
  - **[Complement cohort](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#SegmentFilter)** by using dynamic segments and the `not` option, allowing you to compare to mutually exclusive segments of user (eg compare users who performed a goal vs users who didn't to understand what gets people to convert)
- **Available in both UI and API**
- **Predefined or dynamic**: you either create your segment in the UI and refer to it from the API via its [segmentId](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#Segment.FIELDS.segment_id) or [create a dynamic segment via the API directly](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#dynamicsegment)
- **[Sampling might apply](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2637192?hl=en#adhoc)** so make sure you check for [samplingSpaceSizes](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#ReportData.FIELDS.sampling_space_sizes) to see sampling rate (if any)

**Deciding whether to use segments per se is pretty simply**:

- if you can query what you want without segments don't use them
- if you need them to query what you want, use them

**The challenging part is knowing what you need to query**:

- `Business side`: being able to formulate a hypothesis that makes sense
- `GA side`: being able to translate that into a query, which implies an [understanding of the scopes](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en)